# extracting check-box data from PDFs with Azure Read/OCR API

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-cognitive-services, itext7

I have 1000s of survey forms which I need to scan and then upload onto my C# system in order to extract the data and enter it into a database. The surveys are a mix of hand-written 1) text boxes and 2) checkboxes. I am currently using the the Azure Read Api to extract hand-written text which should work fine e.g. question #4 below returns 'Python' and 'coding'.

So my question; will any Azure API (Read or OCR etc.) give me the capability to extract data for which checkbox is marked? e.g. see question #1 below - I need a string back saying 'disagree', is this possible with any Azure API or will I need to look elsewhere? If so, what API or library can I use to get hand-written checkbox data?

Can somebody with iText7 or IronOCR tell me if these libraries would allow me to extract the checkbox data below?

Survey Example:

[image]

Comment: unless you ask to mark an 'X' as the answer, I don't think it would work for you. You'll need to use a kind of pixel checking to figure out if it's marked as answer or not.

Comment: Thanks Thiago. What's the easiest way to use pixel checking with PDFs?

Comment: @Thiago do you think maybe I could do something like: use pixel checking on each checkbox and if there is anything other than 'o' returned then that means the box is marked?

Comment: Nevermind, just noticed some boxes are square so the reader will not return 'o' in them cases. Would it be possible to check for whitespace if I pass in the pixel cords of inside the boxes ?

Comment: Do you only have 1 form type with 2 pages? If so manually checking each checkbox shouldn't be too difficult - tedious I would say!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDF.Core/ this seems like it could be useful for your problem.

Comment: Azure impresses again. They have a Form Recogniser product in preview too: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/

Comment: @DavidC Thank you for the replies. I have looked at Azure Form Recognizer and unfortunately it does not currently support 'Checkboxes or radio buttons'. I will have to look into IronPDF and see if it offers me something with checkboxes

Comment: @DavidC to answer your first question, I have 4 form types, each form has 2 pages. Could you recommend a way to go about extracting data from checkboxes with the IronOCR library you linked?

Comment: I think for what you need to do you need to rasterize the PDF to an image and then find a known anchor point on the page to look for. Then go looking for each of your check boxes relative to that anchor point. You would have to set bounds around each checkbox to say that "if the pixels within these bounds have > 10% pixels that are not white, then it is checked". Something like that? It's a bit slow, tedious and manual, but achievable! Edit, link to the rasterize method: https://ironpdf.com/examples/rasterize-a-pdf-to-images/

Comment: @DavidC Hi again David, thanks a lot for that! It looks like exactly what I am looking for. If you want to post an answer with the above in it I will accept it as the answer

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know of an easy way I can find x,y bounds for my PDFs?

Comment: I've got GIMP installed on my mac which shows the cursor location in x,y coords, although I'm sure any decent image editor should do it as well. I'll post a more complete answer with all these pieces, although I still think we're a bit away from a legit answer! :)

Comment: I am a lot closer now thanks to you! I am trying to look for some c# sample code to check if color of pixel is above x% in an image. Does this work best with bitmaps or can I use jpg also?

Comment: If you use the IronOCR method `Bitmap[] pageImages = pdf.ToBitmap();` it will create an array of Bitmaps. Once you have the bitmaps you can use standard System.Drawing methods on the bitmap. One of the System.Drawing methods is bitmap.GetPixel() which will return a Color object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel?view=netcore-2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this isn't overly straightforward and involves creating custom code to parse the PDF yourself via a 3rd party library.

Since your forms are of a known shape, you know the locations of the checkboxes. You should construct a dictionary of "Checkbox name" and "Checkbox data" for each checkbox on the page. The data object could be an object that looks like:

```
public class CheckboxData {
    public int startX { get; set; }
    public int startY { get; set; }
    public int endX { get; set; }
    public int endY { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

I would recommend using [IronOCR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDF.Core/) to [rasterize](https://ironpdf.com/examples/rasterize-a-pdf-to-images/) the PDF to an Image.

With your image, iterate over the checkbox dictionary and using the bounding points, move pixel by pixel and get the colour of the pixel. Store the colours in a list and then get the average colour of all pixels within the checkbox. If the average is above a threshold value for determining whether it's checked, set the IsChecked boolean.

For radio styled checkboxes, you will probably need a different data object and store the centre pixel of the circle. For the circles, you should store the centreX and centreY, along with the radius of the circle and use [Bresenham Circle algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#C.23) to know what pixels around that to check.

Below is an example of getting the pixel coordinates in GIMP for where the cursor is.
[image: Getting pixel coordinates of image file]

Comment: Thanks again David, really appreciate the help

Comment: Hi again mate, I have got all the hand-written text extraction working so now I am going to start looking at the checkboxes. Should I also store the average pixel color threshold in CheckboxData? By dictionary, would something like this work: Dictionary<string, CheckboxData> checkboxes = new Dictionary<string, CheckboxData>? string being a name for a specific checkbox? I am just trying to figure out the easiest way to iterate over all off my survey images. I assume bitmap.GetPixel() allows me to pass in the xy cords from CheckboxData? Or how would you suggest doing it?